# Why do I need administrative privileges to use chsh?

Tags: command-line, password, sudo, privileges, etc

I was working on a Ubuntu system where I did not have administrative privileges, and I couldn't change shells (from `tcsh` to `bash`) using `chsh`. I solved the problem writing in the `.tcshrc` to open bash.

I can't understand why I need admin privileges to use `chsh` in my own home directory.
In case I need privileges because `chsh` changes something in the `/etc` folder, how is this any different to changing my password? I can change my password even though I'm not an admin, and this also makes changes within `/etc`.

What's the difference between changing my password and changing my shell?

Comment: The `man chsh` (manpage) says: *"A normal user may only change the login shell for her own account; the superuser may change the login shell for any account."* `chsh username` works for me (on saucy 13.10) without sudo privileges. What version of GNU/Linux Ubuntu & chsh are you using?

Answer (score 2):

Both `chsh` and `passwd` allow the user to change their default shell and password. In both cases the user will be required to provide their current password to authorize the change. The user does not need `sudo` (administrative) privileges.

The command would be:

```
chsh -s /bin/tcsh
```

`chsh tcsh` would not work as it needs the full path. However, you also need to log out and log back in as the X-session will continue to present you with the shell that it read from `/etc/passwd` when it first loaded. A quick way to confirm that indeed your shell has changed would be to switch to one of the virtual terminals and logging in there (such as <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>).